# How do you boot from USB using CentOS Minimal?

Tags: linux, centos

I followed [these instructions](http://blog.lewan.com/2012/02/10/making-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-an-apple-mac-os-x-from-an-iso/) to create a bootable USB using my Mac. This is so I can install CentOS from a USB.

They worked great for the Centos Netinstall and the Centos LiveCD. Both these booted from the USBs on my server.

However, when I did it for the Centos Minimal iso it won't boot. Is this an issue with the Minimal ISO??

I really want to install Centos Minimal, but can only install the full Centos from the LiveCD. I dont want the GUI or any GUI apps.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I guess that Minimal ISO is not a hybrid iso which means it is not dd able(Gentoo minimal is also not dd able. While Arch minimal is dd able).

You can still make it dd able, but it is a bit complex.

I propose you use UltraISO, it can make a bootable liveUSB easily.

Answer (score 0):

try this command.

`dd if=/path/to/iso/file of=/dev/usbdevice`

For example:

`dd if=~/images/xxx-boot.iso of=/dev/sdb`